# How to connect ESP8266 to my home WiFi securely

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I'm working on a home automation project using NodeMCU ESP8266. Most of the example projects I see online provide their WiFi SSID and password in plain text at the beginning of the code by storing them into some variable

Is there a secure way of doing that? I'm worried if my ESP8266 gets hacked by someone online, they'll now have my WiFi SSID and the password. Is there a way of encrypting this information before passing it to ESP8266. Or is there a way of creating a separate WiFi password which will only be used by the ESP8266?

Comment: this may help https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?t=13977

Comment: If the credentials are hardcoded the attacker will have to read out the flash through the internet (which is almost impossible, I guess). Even after that s(he) has to be at your home to login to your wifi, which is very unlikely as long as you are not a person of interest. Providing an interface to the credentials might be more vulnerable than hardcoding them. By the way, the esp supports flash encryption.

Comment: An interesting question. This is not a forum - just a comment section.  But consider that this information is only valuable in close proximity to your house as most wifi is not long range.  And if this really was a risk there are other barriers you can put up like MAC filter on your router.  So why is this a concern?  (BTW, don't use the same password for your router's admin and your router's SSID!)